# Does J.J. Abrams have a fascination towards Oceanic?

Tags: fringe, jj-abrams

Oceanic Air has been a central element in the TV series Lost. But I noticed that Oceanic Air has been used in Fringe too which is also co-produced by J.J. Abrams.

**Oceanic Air ticket in Fringe S01E09**

[image: Oceanic Air ticket in Fringe S01E09]

Does he have any fascination towards Oceanic Air or is it just that it sounds catchy?

Comment: I would say yes, but not so much as an airline, but as a concept. The idea of something being oceanic means that everything is connected. Most Bad Robot works lean towards this, one way or another. The TV series in particular tend to have "Star Wars-like" foundations (family generational saga set in metaphysical universes- with genre skins (espionage, mystery, crime drama, horror) on top. More than Oceanic airlines, it is "Slusho" (derives in Alias, but is fundamental to Cloverfield mythos) and "Kelvin" (name of Abrams' grandfather) that make the biggest appearances across almost all works.

Comment: @DarthLocke: I would like to upvote this if you answer with mentioned connections.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a [popular fictional airline company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_Airlines). It has been used by other directors, like in [Executive Decision](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116253/?ref_=nv_sr_2) by Stuart Baird.

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_Airlines), the footage from this movie

> has been reused in several films and television programs, spreading the Oceanic Airlines brand across various otherwise unrelated fictional universes.